# Solving a travelling salesman problem to maximize gain in minimum time

Tags: algorithm, optimization, puzzle

Team
I need suggestions on how to solve the below problem.
There are n places (for example say 10 places). Time taken from any one place to the other is known. On reaching a particular place a known reward is given in the form of rupees (ex. if I travel from place 1 to place 2, I get 100 rupees. Travelling from place 2 to place 3 will fetch me 50 rupees etc...). Also, sometimes a particular place is unavailable to travel to which changes with time. At all time instances, whatever places can be traveled to is known, reward fetched from each place is known and the time taken to travel from one place to other is known. This is an ongoing process, meaning after you reach place A and earn 100 rupees, you travelled to place B and fetch 100 Rs. Then it is possible that place A can again fetch you rupees say 50 if you travel from B to A again.

Problem statement is:

**A path should be followed with time ( A to B, B to C, C to B, B to A etc...) so that I always have maximum rupees in a given time.** Thus at the end of 1 month, I should have followed a path that fetches me the maximum amount among all possibilities available.

Comment: If you revisit a place, do you get the reward twice?

Comment: How long are we allowed to wait in one place? Can we wait a few days, a week, two weeks?

Comment: @user58697 the problem description includes a scenario where a place is revisited.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Right, but it says nothing about collecting multiple rewards at the same place.

Comment: @user58697 "it is possible that place A can again fetch you rupees say 50"

Comment: @user58697: if we revisit a place then yes you will again get reward but this reward might change.There is zero waiting. We just need to go, take reward and leave the place.

Answer (score 1):

We already know that in the traveling salesman problem it takes `O(N!)` to calculate the best way for the month if there are no changes. Because of the unknown changes that can happen, the best way is to use a greedy algorithm such that every time you come to new place, you calculate where you get the most R's in the least amount of time. It will take `O(N*k)` where k is the amount of time that you move between places in a month.

Comment: how can we just use greedy here? At any time decision should be made based on available credits at all available places.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this problem is related to travelling salesman -- I understood the latter as having the restriction of at least visiting all the places once.

Assuming we have all of the time instances and their related information ahead of our calculation, if we work backwards from each place we imagine ending at, the choices we have for the previous location visited dictate the possible times it took to get to the last place and the possible earning we could have gotten. Clearly from those choices we would choose the best reward among them because it's our last choice. Apply this idea recursively from there, until we reach the start of the month. If we run this recursion from each possible ending place, we can reuse states we've seen before; for example if we reached place A at time T as one of the options when calculating backwards from B, and then we reach A again at time T when calculating a path that started at C, we can reuse the record for the first state. The search space would be O(N*T) but practically would vary with the input.

Something like this? (Assumes we cannot wait in any one place. Otherwise, the solution could be better coded bottom-up where we can try all place + time states.) Return the best of running `f` with the same `memo` map on all possible ending states.

```py
get_travel_time(place_a, place_b):
  # returns travel time from place a to place b


get_neighbours(place):
  # returns places from which we can travel to place


get_reward(place, time):
  # returns the reward awarded at place place at time time


f(place, time, memo={}):
  if time == 0:
    return 0

  key = (place, time)

  if key in memo:
    return memo[key]

  current_reward = get_reward(place, time)
  best = -Infinity

  for neighbour in get_neighbours(place):
    previous_time = time - get_travel_time(neighbour, place)

    if previous_time >= 0:
      best = max(best, current_reward + f(neighbour, previous_time, memo))

  memo[key] = best

  return memo[key]
```

Comment: We should visit all the places based on achieving maximum reward in a given time. At any time decision to move from one place should be taken based on reward achieved at various places and time taken for travel. I can't understand how you are trying to solve, maybe if you can share any reference video/webpage to get an idea on how to solve this

Comment: @ManojGupta the description you have posted does not include a stipulation that all places be visited at least once, although you have clarified in the comments that places may be visited more than once. Can you please add any missing constraints in the question description?

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication. There is no constraint that each place should be visited atleast once . Only objective is to fetch maximum reward in a given time . Suppose there are 4 places A,B,C,D. There are rewards at some or all places which changes with time.  Suppose for example reward is at all places

Comment: @ManojGupta I added pseudocode for the direction I was thinking about. I cannot guarantee that it's bug free.